# spacyr on MacOS: "Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded"

Tags: r, rstudio, quanteda

I have read the similar questions and answers on Stack Overflow but have not cracked this issue. I could be doing something wrong based on those prior answers and just need further guidance. I've included the sessionInfo() below.

### Problem

Using RStudio on a MacOS, I have the **spacyr** loaded. I also have **miniconda** installed on my computer. However, after running:

```
spacy_initialize()
```

I get:

> Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
> Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.

Which is puzzling since I have miniconda installed. I'm guessing that when I downloaded miniconda, I didn't do it as a "shared environment". Perhaps something is getting messed up because my 2017 Macbook came preloaded with an old version of Python, whereas the minconda one is Python 3.9.

I don't know. I'm prepared to do some uninstall/reinstalls and go into the terminal if necessary, but people might have to explain it to me like I'm five.

I appreciate the help.

### sessionInfo()

> R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
> (64-bit) Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6
>
> Matrix products: default LAPACK:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale:   [1]
> en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:   [1] reticulate_1.22   spacyr_1.2.1
> textrecipes_0.4.1 recipes_0.1.17    [5] cleanNLP_3.0.3
> hunspell_3.0.1    SnowballC_0.7.0   gt_0.3.1          [9]
> magrittr_2.0.1    rmarkdown_2.11    htmltools_0.5.2   rlang_0.4.12
> [13] stopwords_2.2     quanteda_3.1.0    text2vec_0.6
> corpus_0.10.2     [17] bench_1.1.1       jiebaR_0.11       jiebaRD_0.1
> janeaustenr_0.1.5 [21] hcandersenr_0.2.0 tidytext_0.3.2
> forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     [25] dplyr_1.0.7       purrr_0.3.4
> readr_2.0.2       tidyr_1.1.4       [29] tibble_3.1.5
> ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1   tokenizers_0.2.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):   [1] colorspace_2.0-2
> ellipsis_0.3.2       class_7.3-19         [4] rprojroot_2.0.2
> fs_1.5.0             rstudioapi_0.13      [7] listenv_0.8.0
> remotes_2.4.1        prodlim_2019.11.13   [10] fansi_0.5.0
> lubridate_1.8.0      xml2_1.3.2           [13] codetools_0.2-18
> splines_4.1.1        cachem_1.0.6         [16] rsparse_0.4.0
> knitr_1.36           pkgload_1.2.3        [19] mlapi_0.1.0
> jsonlite_1.7.2       RhpcBLASctl_0.21-247 [22] broom_0.7.9
> dbplyr_2.1.1         png_0.1-7            [25] compiler_4.1.1
> httr_1.4.2           backports_1.2.1      [28] assertthat_0.2.1
> Matrix_1.3-4         fastmap_1.1.0        [31] cli_3.0.1
> prettyunits_1.1.1    tools_4.1.1          [34] gtable_0.3.0
> glue_1.4.2           float_0.2-6          [37] fastmatch_1.1-3
> Rcpp_1.0.7           cellranger_1.1.0     [40] vctrs_0.3.8
> timeDate_3043.102    xfun_0.27            [43] gower_0.2.2
> globals_0.14.0       ps_1.6.0             [46] testthat_3.1.0
> rvest_1.0.2          lifecycle_1.0.1      [49] devtools_2.4.2
> future_1.22.1        MASS_7.3-54          [52] scales_1.1.1
> ipred_0.9-12         lgr_0.4.3            [55] hms_1.1.1
> parallel_4.1.1       yaml_2.2.1           [58] memoise_2.0.0
> rpart_4.1-15         stringi_1.7.5        [61] desc_1.4.0
> pkgbuild_1.2.0       lava_1.6.10          [64] pkgconfig_2.0.3
> evaluate_0.14        lattice_0.20-45      [67] processx_3.5.2
> tidyselect_1.1.1     parallelly_1.28.1    [70] R6_2.5.1
> generics_0.1.0       DBI_1.1.1            [73] pillar_1.6.4
> haven_2.4.3          withr_2.4.2          [76] nnet_7.3-16
> survival_3.2-13      future.apply_1.8.1   [79] modelr_0.1.8
> crayon_1.4.1         utf8_1.2.2           [82] tzdb_0.1.2
> usethis_2.1.0        grid_4.1.1           [85] readxl_1.3.1
> data.table_1.14.2    callr_3.7.0          [88] reprex_2.0.1
> digest_0.6.28        RcppParallel_5.1.4   [91] munsell_0.5.0
> sessioninfo_1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Someone provided me with a solution.

Have loaded: **reticulate** and **spacyr** packages.

Turns out that the **reticulate** package doesn't follow the standard way of indicating which version of Python you'd like to use, at least on a Mac OS, which has a system-level default that R wants to use.

The workaround is to set the system environment variable to tell reticulate to the attach the desired conda environment.

```
Sys.setenv( RETICULATE_PYTHON = with(conda_list(), python[ name == "spacy_condaenv" ]))
```

Next, run `spacy_initialize()`. Should work now.

Going forward, you'll need to put the Sys.setenv code (as written above) at the top of your script so that R sets the system environment to your liking right when you start a session.